# Map marker won't show

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I am totally lost, my marker won't show on the map. I did the exactly as shown on the Google Maps example. I can't get the marker to appear on mylatlng. The icon image is in the same folder as the html page.

```
$("#b1").on("click",function(){
  function initialize(){
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.7404, -74.1789);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom:5,
      center: myLatLng
    }
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOptions);
    var image = 'marker.png';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.64043,-74.2789);
    var Name = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      icon: image
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
  });
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);
```

UPDATE:

FIGURED IT OUT. I need to have `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);` outside the function.

UPDATE 2:
  well i don't need to have the 'initialize' within `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialise);` if i do that. it would create only one marker. After deleting the it, marker is working for all the 30 onClick list that i have. And yeah i don't need the function initialize()

Comment: When the image and the HTML-page are located in the same folder you should remove the slash (a slash at the begin of a path marks the root-folder, so the image is expected to be in the DOCUMENT_ROOT of your server)

Comment: i removed the slash but its still not showing.

Comment: you are using 'var name' as your marker instance so make it name.setMap(map);

Comment: Warning: initialise ≠ initialize

Answer (score 1):

Couple of mistakes here ,

1:You were using wrong marker variable to set Map,initialize marker  as  global variable.

2:To get map display you have to use [Google map Dom Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#DomEvents) `google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('yourbuttonid'), 'click', initialize);`

3:And it will be out of the intialise function.

[`Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/VEVaJ/)